# Java Array of references / several different classes?

Tags: java, arrays, class, reference, chess

I'm new here and although I've found a lot of information here many times, this is my first question, so let me now if I should change my way of asking or something.

Well, I am trying to create a simple chess Java program, and for this I have created a different class for every different kind of piece (Knight, Queen, Pawn...), but now I need to store all of them in the same array in order to set and get their position on the board.

To do this, I thought of creating an integer array that would store the references to the different objects in the right place, and nulls or zeros wherever there was no piece at all, but I have encountered with soooo many problems for this.

I also thought of creating a superclass called "pieces" or something, and an array of this class. This way, using switch, I could call each subclass depending on the value (1 for pawn, 2 for knight...), but that seems to be way too shabby since I should modify many things and I'm sure that there are better-looking ways to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is some code from my class Queen, so you know how I code:

```
 public class Queen {
        //Clase de la mejor banda de música de la historia

    //Color. True when white, false when black.
    private final boolean color;
    //Parametres for position
    private int x, y;

    public Queen(boolean c, int x, int y){
        color = c;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String a;
        if(color) a="q";
        else a="Q";
        return a;
    }
    /* Checks if the movement to the given space is possible or not.
     * Returns true if possible, false if not.
     */
    public boolean checkMove(int i, int j){
        //Checks that the given space is right
        if(i<1||i>8||j<1||j>8) return false;
        //Space is the same of the piece
        else if(i==x&&j==y) return false;
        //Given space is in the same column as the piece
        else if(i==x){
            //Space is under the piece
            if(j>y){

            }
            //Space is over the piece
            else if(j<y){

            }           
        }
        //Given space is in the same row as the piece
        else if(j==y){
            //Space is to the right of the piece
            if(i>x){

            }
            //Space is to the left of the piece
            else if(i<x){

            }
        }
        //DIAGONALS
        else{
            //Space is in a diagonal, down left of the piece
            for(int aux_x=x, aux_y=y; aux_x>1 && aux_y<8; aux_x--, aux_y++){
                if(aux_x==i && aux_y==j){

                }
                else if(Grid.board)
            }
            //
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: use one baseclass or a common interface for each figure class. In addition you mentioned using values as identifikator, you should take a look at enums, which would be prefered here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As this is about *coding* -  we'd like to see some code. As this is about *helping to help yourself* - show us what you've tried so far. Where does it break? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well, my code doesn't really break since I haven't tried to compile it yet, because I have encountered this problem while thinking on how to do it. Anyway, I'm gonna post my class Queen (The one I have developed the most), so you can see what I'm trying to do with each class. It's not complete, but it's a template of the way I work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a superclass called `ChessPiece`, inherit all your classes from this class (as all are chess pieces). `ChessPiece` will have a variables which will represent where the piece currently is. This seems to be the most standard practice.

e.g.

```
public abstract class ChessPiece {

       // fields
        protected boolean isWhite; // true if this is a white piece
        protected int row; // current chess piece row
        protected int col; // current chess piece column
```

Then, you can create an `ArrayList` of `ChessPiece` and get / set their locations.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to ask you with an example because I really don't know how to implement it. If I create an object King, it inherits the attributes from ChessPiece. Till there I'm fine, but how can I differenciate which object is the one is space [3][4] if the array is made for Chesspiece? Is there a way to access specific methods of the subclasses from the superclass without an attribute that states which kind of piece is it?

Comment: Yes there is a way, read about `instanceof` operator. e.g. `if ( someObj instanceof Queen ) {  Queen queen = (Queen)someObj;
     // do something with queen
  }`

Comment: Thanks, I'll read about that. Until now I've simply used instanceof for overriding the method equals(), but I guess that there are some  more applications

Answer (score 0):

Consider this Interface:

```
public interface ChessPiece {       
    public enum Color { BLACK, WHITE };

    public Color getColor();

    //Check if move to (i,j) is possible
    public boolean checkMove(int i, int j);    
}
```

And this change to your Queen:

```
public class Queen implements ChessPiece {
        //Clase de la mejor banda de música de la historia

    //Color. True when white, false when black.
    private final Color color;
    //Parametres for position
    private int x, y;

    public Queen(Color c, int x, int y){
        color = c;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String toString(){
        if(Color.BLACK.equals(color)) {
            return "q";
        } else {
            return "Q";
        }

    }

    /* Checks if the movement to the given space is possible or not.
     * Returns true if possible, false if not.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean checkMove(int i, int j){
        //Checks that the given space is right
        if(i<1||i>8||j<1||j>8) return false;
        //Space is the same of the piece
        else if(i==x&&j==y) return false;

        [...]
    }
}
```

Now you can simply hold all the pieces in arrays or lists:

```
List<ChessPiece> onBoard = new ArrayList<ChessPiece>();
//Now add a queen
onBoard.add(new Queen(ChessPiece.Color.WHITE, 1, 4));
```

And they all can tell you if a move would be valid:

```
public boolean isCheck(Color c) {
  Point p = getPositionOfKing(c);

  for(int i = 0; i <8; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j <8; ++j) {
      ChessPiece cp = getAt(i,j);
      if(cp != null && !cp.getColor().equals(c)) {
        if(cp.isValidMode(p.x, p.y)) {
          //The piece on i, j could capture the king!
        }
      }
    }
 } 
}
```